# Get git branch name in Jenkins Pipeline/Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, branch, jenkins-pipeline

I've create a jenkins pipeline and it is pulling the pipeline script from scm.
I set the branch specifier to '`all`', so it builds on any change to any branch.

How do I access the branch name causing this build from the Jenkinsfile?

Everything I have tried echos out null except

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
```

which is always `master`.

Comment: If you are using [GitHub Pull Request Builder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ghprb/) plugin, you can use `${env.ghprbSourceBranch}` or even `${env.ghprbActualCommit}`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have a jenkinsfile for your pipeline, check if you see at execution time your branch name in your [environment variables](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/).

You can print them with:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DISABLE_AUTH = 'true'
        DB_ENGINE    = 'sqlite'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, [PR 91](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/pull/91) shows that the branch name is only set in certain pipeline configurations:

- [Branch Conditional](https://github.com/abayer/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/0d74f6bc326ff8d2407ae488d268c8861953fd78/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/when/impl/BranchConditional.java) (see this [groovy script](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/2095b27d9eab34bfb0f2f99e4a11b5eaad93e3dd/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/when/impl/BranchConditionalScript.groovy#L39))
- [parallel branches pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/commit/d2f057db00e7fe48dbc6029f687ee37d646b5b09#diff-201d1947d4dbd8cbcd8e2ba74cd68028) (as seen by the OP)

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Looks like it is not in my environment variables. Is it possible to expose the branch that caused the build?

Comment: This is ridiculous that a file in the repo (the Jenkinsfile) would ever be expected to provide a hardcoded branch name.  This makes the repo itself a disaster to manage.  This needs fixing...

Answer (score 91):

Use **multibranch pipeline** job type, not the plain ***pipeline*** job type. The multibranch pipeline jobs do posess the environment variable `env.BRANCH_NAME` which describes the branch.

In my script..

```
stage('Build') {
    node {
        echo 'Pulling...' + env.BRANCH_NAME
        checkout scm
        
    }
}
```

Yields...

```
Pulling...master
```

Comment: This is actually just the name of the job, not of the git branch. This works as long as your jobs have the same name as your branches.

Comment: And also all these variables are defined on the Git plugin's page here under Environment Variables: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git

Comment: `env.BRANCH_NAME` is the name of the job??

Comment: @Danijel, yes, for Multibranch Pipelines, the name of the job is the name of the branch.  The pipeline still has whatever name you give it, but it creates a job for each branch (each pattern that you enabled), and those job names are the branch names.

Answer (score 42):

A colleague told me to use `scm.branches[0].name` and it worked. I wrapped it to a function in my Jenkinsfile:

```
def getGitBranchName() {
    return scm.branches[0].name
}
```

Comment: Tried that and got.. 
 
...org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: 

Scripts not permitted to use method


BRANCH_NAME does not work and env.BRANCH_NAME returns null...

Comment: If you set the shared library as global you will not have security issues. The other way is to allow those security exceptions on the `Manage Jenkins > In Process Script Approval`

Comment: You can also whitelist that method

Comment: WINNER. Works great! No shell execution. No initial need to checkout anything. Works on a different node context. Works on a plain project. Good stuff.

Comment: This works for me. How to find out the properties of the `scm` object? Is there any documentation for this object? Thanks.

Comment: Here you have the object specs: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

Comment: Note this only works if you are using "Pipeline script from SCM", and not if your Pipeline script is in Jenkins itself.

Answer (score 22):

For pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  environment {
     BRANCH_NAME = "${GIT_BRANCH.split("/")[1]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have adapted your answer to make it work on simple pipeline and also on multibranch pipelines where there is not need to split `GIT_BRANCH` with this condition: `BRANCH_NAME = "${GIT_BRANCH.split("/").size() > 1 ? GIT_BRANCH.split("/")[1] : GIT_BRANCH}"`

Comment: To improve @Romain's comment further: `BRANCH_NAME = "${GIT_BRANCH.split('/').size() > 1 ? GIT_BRANCH.split('/')[1..-1].join('/') : GIT_BRANCH}"`

Comment: Take into consideration that branch names will always starts with `origin/<branch-name>`,  an improved version for all scenarios : `branchName = "${env.GIT_BRANCH.split('/').size() == 1 ? env.GIT_BRANCH.split('/')[-1] : env.GIT_BRANCH.split('/')[1..-1].join('/')}"`

Answer (score 13):

For me this worked: (using Jenkins 2.150, using simple Pipeline type - not multibranch, my branch specifier: '**')

```
echo 'Pulling... ' + env.GIT_BRANCH
```

Output:

```
Pulling... origin/myBranch
```

where myBranch is the name of the feature branch

Comment: This doesn't work, the result is pulling null. This answer is only useable if you specify more than just your version number, for instance, are you using any plug-ins that do the magic for you?

Comment: @chrillelundmark I edited my answer after trying again... I did not install a plugin to help me with that purpose, otherwise I don't know what else I should specify... I guess there are not enough characters in one comment to write down all my plugins

Comment: I am getting `PR-45=` as a value of env.GIT_BRANCH when my jenkins job is triggered from PR. Not something I'd expect

Comment: That returns null for me using Jenkins 2.303.1 on Windows, simple pipeline.

Answer (score 7):

This is for simple Pipeline type - not multibranch. Using Jenkins 2.150.1

```
environment {
    FULL_PATH_BRANCH = "${sh(script:'git name-rev --name-only HEAD', returnStdout: true)}"
    GIT_BRANCH = FULL_PATH_BRANCH.substring(FULL_PATH_BRANCH.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, FULL_PATH_BRANCH.length())
  }
```

then use it `env.GIT_BRANCH`

Comment: This works great for me on a macOS slave however on the Windows slave I always get 'null' returned when doing 

    environment {
                                            FULL_PATH_BRANCH_WIN = "${bat(script:'@git name-rev --name-only HEAD', returnStdout: true)}"
                                                GIT_BRANCH_WIN = FULL_PATH_BRANCH_WIN.substring(FULL_PATH_BRANCH_WIN.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, FULL_PATH_BRANCH_WIN.length())
                                        }

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 234: unexpected token: name @ line 234, column 42.
   TH_BRANCH = “${sh(script:‘git name-rev -                                                                       Did't worked for me

Comment: FULL_PATH_BRANCH returns null for me using Jenkins 2.303.1 on Windows, simple pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

Switching to a multibranch pipeline allowed me to access the branch name. A regular pipeline was not advised.

Comment: Yes, reading https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/pull/91, you should see it in `BRANCH_NAME`.

Answer (score 5):

Just getting the name from `scm.branches` is not enough if you've used a build parameter as a branch specifier, e.g. `${BRANCH}`.
You need to expand that string into a real name:

```
scm.branches.first().getExpandedName(env.getEnvironment())
```

Note that `getEnvironment()` must be an explicit getter otherwise `env` will look up for an environment variable called **environment**.

Don't forget that you need to approve those methods to make them accessible from the sandbox.

Answer (score 5):

To get git branch name in Jenkins,
If it is a **multibranch pipeline** then we can easily use the **env.GIT_BRANCH**.
But if it is a normal pipeline then we can use the SCM plugin object to retrieve the branch name.

The below code works for both normal as well as multibranch pipelines.

```
def branch_nem = scm.branches[0].name
if (branch_nem.contains("*/")) {
    branch_nem = branch_nem.split("\\*/")[1]
    }
echo branch_nem
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW the only thing that worked for me in PR builds was `${CHANGE_BRANCH}`

(may not work on `master`, haven't seen that yet)

Comment: CHANGE_BRANCH did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me for non-multi-branch pipeline with either setting SCM `Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')` to `*/branch_name` or setting it to just `branch_name`:

```
BRANCH_NAME = "${GIT_BRANCH.split('/').size() > 1 ? GIT_BRANCH.split('/')[1..-1].join('/') : GIT_BRANCH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I might want to use `env.CHANGE_BRANCH` to get real branch name instead of jenkins job / PR name.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the necessity when you are working with just Jenkins `Pipelines`, I created the following function in a `Shared Library`:

```
package org.helpers

class Helpers {
    static def getBranchName(String branchName){
        return branchName.split('/').size() == 1 ? branchName.split('/')[-1] : branchName.split('/')[1..-1].join('/')
    }
}
```

From the pipeline I accessed that static method (my shared library was registered with the name `pipelines`):

```
@Library("pipelines") _
def helper = org.helpers.Helpers
pipeline {
        agent any
        environment {
            branchName = helper.getBranchName("${env.GIT_BRANCH}")
        }
       stages {
         stage('test'){
           agent any
           steps {
             script { sh "echo 'branchName: ${branchName}'" }
           }
         }
       }
}
```