# BranchName in a PR on JenkinsFile

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, pull-request

I use Jenkins file, 
How can I have the exact name of the current branch in my jenkinsFile, during a Pull Request?

The var BRANCH_NAME contains only something who start why 'PR-'

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383273/get-git-branch-name-in-jenkins-jenkinsfile

Comment: the solution work in local, but return null when launched by jenkins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get git branch name in Jenkins Pipeline/Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383273/get-git-branch-name-in-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile)